# How to implement linked data in Dspace, using Fuseki?

Tags: dspace

I need to implement Dspace Linked Data using Fuseki, but I can not find  specific documentation about that

Do you know how I can implement Linked Data in Dspace, and use Fuseki?

Comment: See https://github.com/DSpace-Labs/DSpace-Docker-Images/blob/master/docker-compose-files/dspace-compose/ComposeFiles.md#add-the-rdf-service-dspace6-and-dspace7 for testing in Docker

Answer (score 0):

checkout  the link below. Can short out your issue of linked data https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Linked+%28Open%29+Data